# How to convert an arbitrary SQL statement to column level lineage information via an open source solution?

Tags: data-lineage

I have SQL statements (various dialects). I want to get column level lineage information for each statement.

Example:
The statement

```
SELECT A.c1 as c, 
       SUM(B.c2) as c2_sum
FROM A
JOIN B
  ON A.c1 = B.c1
```

leads to something like

```
{
  "c": ["A.c1", "B.c2"],
  "c2_sum": ["B.c2"],
}
```

The SQL statements are mostly quite close to the standard. It is Spark SQL, PostgreSQL, Presto, Athena SQL.